# Spring OAuth2 with implicit and password flows

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to setup a project with Spring OAuth 2 using implicit, password and authorization flows.

The problem I have appears when I use the same token endpoint for implicit and the other two, password and authorization needs the basic authentication for client validation while implicit doesn't validate the client secret and I want to use a more clasical login/password authentication for user authorization.

So depending on the configuration one or two flows work.
Having 2 endpoints seems to be the easiest solution, but I can not find how to achieve that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
<!--
    <sec:http pattern="/external/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/external/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>
-->
    <sec:http pattern="/external/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/external/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <sec:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="blablabla" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenStore" class="com.proton.oauthprovider.service.ProtOnTokenStore" />

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="com.proton.oauthprovider.service.ProtOnClientDetailsService" />

    <bean id="oauthCodeDetails" class="com.proton.oauthprovider.service.ProtOnAuthorizationCodeServices" />

    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="com.proton.oauthprovider.service.OAuthUserApprovalHandler">
        <property name="autoApproveClients">
            <set>
                <!--  <value>rest-client</value> -->
            </set>
        </property>
        <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails"  
        token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler" authorization-endpoint-url="/external/oauth/authorize" 
        user-approval-page="forward:/external/oauth/confirm_access" 
        error-page="forward:/external/oauth/error" 
        token-endpoint-url="/external/oauth/token" >
        <oauth:authorization-code authorization-code-services-ref="oauthCodeDetails"/>
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

    <!-- Override the default mappings for approval and error pages -->
    <bean id="accessConfirmationController" class="com.proton.oauthprovider.controller.AccessConfirmationController">
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

authenticationEntryPoint is the login form entry point, and the custom classes are more or less the same from sparklr and tonr just using DB backend for storing client and token data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got everything wrong, implicit flow does not use token endpoint, it uses authorize one.
So the previous config is ok and I only needed to point implicit flow to /oauth/authorize/ and it works as expected.

Comment: I am not sure how you get it working this way. For Spring oAuth2 password flow, you should get access token from /oauth/token. I got the same 404 error as well, and my case fits your description. My problem was because I didn't properly set up the DispatcherServlet in web.xml.